# Using SQL temp table inside of select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join, temporary

I am trying to create a search engine that filters and preform searches by using values from two tables.

I have managed to create a temporary table by inner joining two tables together. However I cannot figure a way to get the mysql query to search from the temp table.

```
$search_query = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, major, location, class_of, campus, avatar, state, country 

FROM ('SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.location, users.country, tags_game.name, tags_interest.name, tags_movie.name FROM users, tags_game, tags_interest, tags_movie WHERE users.id IN (tags_game.relation, tags_interest.relation, tags_movie.relation)')
                somealias

WHERE first_name LIKE '{$first_name}%' && 
    location LIKE '{$location}%' &&     
    state LIKE '{$state}%' &&
    country LIKE '{$country}%'
```

However this doesn't work. How do I use/call temp tables inside other queries?

Comment: you can't use sub queries like that.

Comment: How would I add a temp table inside a query then?

Comment: `WHERE SOMTHING IN ('SELECT table1.something_1, table2.something_2 . . .')`

Comment: You mean something like this:
mysql_query("SELECT something_1, something_2 WHERE something_1 = '0' && something_2 = '0' IN ('SELECT table1.something_1, table2.something_2. . . ')")

Comment: The quotes around the subselect are totally wrong. It has to be `(select ...) ` not `('select...')`

Comment: @samitha: of course you can use a "sub-select" like that. It's called a derived table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery needs an alias name otherwise it won't work. This returns 1 :

```
SELECT test from  -- or fully qualified : aliasname.test
  (SELECT 1 as test) aliasname
WHERE test>0
```

So I presume you require something like :

```
mysql_query("SELECT something_1, something_2 . . . FROM
  (SELECT table1.something_1, table2.something_2 . . .) somealias WHERE . . .");
```

Comment: I am a bit confused on how to use the alias for my table, do you mind showing me how alias name would be used for the temp table and the query? How would that look with those two?

Comment: In this case the aliasname isn't actually used - but SQL requires it. If I have misunderstood what you're trying to achieve please do say so and I'll delete my answer so that someone else can help.

Comment: I am just simply trying to take a temp table I have created through combining two tables and having a query take data FROM that temp table. Do you know how to get that to work? Do you know how to get this to work with aliasname so that the query is able to select information from that temp table?

Comment: Once you've got your query working, you can place it within `( here! ) aliasname` and use it as a 'derived table' for an outer level query. I'll edit my answer in a moment to show what I presume you're trying to do from the example you've given.

Comment: I tried it, but I ended up getting a syntax error. I edited my original post to include the real actual code of the query and temp table, do you mind telling me what did I do wrong?

Comment: Try it without the quotes around the inner SELECT